# Squealing noise when reversing and turning, from RHS of car

Tags: brakes, civic

I drive a 2010 Civic with about 80k kilometers on it and it makes a screeching or squealing noise when I drive.

I've checked other relevant posts + googling, and I suspect brakes, not the fan belt (because the noise is not constant). Here's what I've seen:

- When driving, sometimes there's a noise (like an oscillation); most often when/after I turn right. It increases in frequency with the car velocity.
- The noise occurs sometimes when driving straight or turning left.
- The noise didn't occur in the rain.
- Overnight, the probability of the noise occurring dropped.
- The noise doesn't occur when I brake.
- When reversing, there's a constant screeching noise.

Is it my brakes, or something else? I had a test-drive with a mechanic, and he suggested that it is indeed the brakes, most likely the rear ones. (I'll find out tomorrow when he opens it up.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanic is most likely spot on. Disk brakes (assuming you have rear disk brakes) have what is called a *squealer* on them. When the pad gets thin enough, the squealer touches the rotor. As it rotates, the squealer ... well ... *squeals*. This is most likely the noise you are hearing. When you press on the brakes, the squealer is pressed harder against the rotor and quits making the noise.

Comment: If that's true, why would this only happen when I reverse or turn on one side?

Comment: @ashes999 - You said it "*occurs sometimes when driving straight or turning left*" ... that implies to me it happens not just when backing up. Squealers may not make a constant noise, but all indications you've given are pointing towards it being the brakes which are your issue.